# Is watt unit depended on turbine speed

Tags: energy, electricity, power

Is watt unit depended on speed of turbine? I think, if turbine rotates more speed it will produce more watts. Is it right?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking whether the *power* (physical quantity, given in units of watts) generated by a turbine depends on its rotational frequency?

Comment: This is either a ridiculous question or a very badly worded one.  No, of course not, the definition of a Watt doesn't change because someone ran a turbine faster somewhere.  A Watt is 1 Joule per second, or in fundamental units, one kilogram meter squared per second cubed.  This remains the same regardless of what happens to your turbine, someone else's turbine, or how many tomatoes fit on a windowsill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a watt is one joule of energy per second.

A given Wind turbine produces more energy per second (more watts) when it is rotating faster.

Power of a wind turbine is proportional to the cube of the wind speed.